# Final Year Project - Title Suggestions

Tags: computer-science, signal-processing, speech

I'm a Computer Science student and have to complete my final year project. I am looking for title suggestions as this actually seems to be the most complicated aspect of the whole project. Basically, my project is:

- Developing an algorithm that analyses Speech, specifically detecting if someone is saying either "Yes" or "No" and then determine if the person is either male or female.

@mmoment

I'm going to develop an algorithm that determines if a sample (a person's voice) is either saying "Yes" or "No". The algorithm will work by splitting the sample into blocks, and, then finding the zero-crossings of each block and then using HMM's to determine if someone is saying either "Yes" or "No". This can be done, I believe, by picking out Phones. For example, if the Phone "Y" is picked out, then we can infer that the word is Yes, however, if the Phone isn't "Y" /or/ "N" then we can infer that the word is No. Does this make sense?

There are some issues relating to this problem, I know and before I submit my final proposal, I will "iron" them out and hopefully come to a final decision.

I hope someone can help me :)!

Comment: Is this question related to programming?

Comment: I don't understand why I have -2 negative feedback.. What the hell is the matter with the question? :S

Comment: it actually is be related to dsp programming, mathematical signal analysis and neural networks if phorce does not just reuse existing packages. @Phorce would you mind describing you problem, intended solution approach etc? I personally would go for Matlab because a lot of fundamental solution aproaches can be easily implemented with Matlab.

Comment: @mmoment I hav edited my post to explain my problem a bit better. :)

Comment: Do you actually think coming up with a title is going to be the most difficult aspect of the project?

Comment: @DavidRobinson Considering, I've already tackled most problems, the title is the difficulty at the minute. Like being at school, I'm sure you found the first sentence / paragraph to write and then once you had that, the rest seemed relatively easy. IMO anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A friend of mine worked on a similar project and evaluated the use of hidden markov chains/models for speech recognition:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model

Also, the use of Matlab is highly recommended ( It requires some special toolboxes though ).

@Phorce instead of going for the zero crossings, why not transfer the time continuous signal into another domain ( you would do that anyways, into the time discrete fourier domain ) and check for base frequencies and occurences of significant ripple harmonic frequencies? That should do the trick determining the difference between YES or NO.
This would dismiss any significant relevance of the amplitudes and distinction would be fairly easy.
The real task here is to determine different pronounciations, which would probably just be  a stretch of the signal / bandwidth or a shift in the frequency domain.

The shift in the frequency domain will also help to distinguish femal from male speakers.. but you will probably have to use some form of neural network so your system can learn / adapt to different speakers, voices etc ..!

Comment: Hello, do you think it's a interesting project for me to do then? By transferring the signals, you would need to use a FFT, correct? I would like to use a different method over Zero-crossing, in all honesty, but, still using HMM for probability. I want to use C++ over MatLab. My main issue is I don't want to have to write an FFT. Thanks for your help, any further advice would be greatly appreciated :)!

Comment: Go for the z-transform. it's simple, fast, and efficient if you select the proper sampling frequency!

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transformation

It is also fairly simple to be implemented onto an embedded / dsp device.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll defiantly look into it. So I can use the z-transform, put it back into the frequency domain then instead of using zero-crossing, then determine using harmonic frequencies and finally using HMM's as probability to identify if someone is saying 'Yes', 'No', does this sound like an ok-rough idea?

Comment: Could I also find the total energy? I'm looking for characteristics in the speech, remember. :)

Comment: yes, z-transform can help you do this as well

Comment: Would Linear Predictive Coding come into play in any of this? I'm going to buy a book!